# window is not defined server side rendering

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am getting following error:

> /Users/Picchu/Documents/em/node_modules/ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js:2143
>   })(window);    ^
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at Object. (/Users/Picchu/Documents/em/node_modules/ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js:2143:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/Users/Picchu/Documents/em/dist/server.js:18652:18)
>       at **webpack_require** (/Users/Picchu/Documents/em/dist/server.js:20:30)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: where I need to change?

Comment: The library `ng2-mqtt` is using the `window` object without checking if it exists. This is a problem for server side rendering since `window` is unknown on the server side. Your best guess is to submit an issue on their github page and hope they fix it

Comment: Ok but I am using the libraries within my node_modules. Is there not an other way to solve it? For example with webpack?